# rank of a regression-like model

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Ley $y$ be an $n \times 1$ vector and $X$ be an $n \times k$ matrix, and that $y$ and $X$ have the following relationship
\begin{equation}
y = c + AXb
\end{equation}
where $c$ is $n \times 1$, $A$ is $n \times n$ and $b$ is $k \times 1$. Assume that $A \neq I_n$, $A \neq 0$, $b \neq 0$ and $X$ has full column rank.

Under this setup, I want to show that $[y,X]$ has full column rank.

When $c=0$, $[y,X]$ should have full rank since $A \neq I$ and $y$ cannot be expressed as a linear combination of $X$.

When $c \neq 0$, I want to prove that there does not exist a vector $d$ such that
\begin{equation}
c + AXb =Xd
\end{equation}
Although such d should not exist, I cannot prove it... Any help or alternative proof would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The vector $c$ is unrestricted. Therefore you obtain a counterexample if you *define* $c$ by the relationship

$$c + AXb =Xd$$

for some $d\neq 0$.

Of course if you simulate such a model with $X$ independent from $c,A,b$ then you should have full rank "almost surely".

Comment: Many thanks. If it is further assumed that $[c, X]$ has full column rank, can you prove that $[y,X]$ has full column rank?

Comment: @user0131 I think you can still find a counterexample.